# How can I get my former employer to pay my notice and give me my P45?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, notice-period, employer

I was working at a company in the UK, they fired me and put me on gardening leave for my notice (4 weeks). Now the notice period is over they've not paid me for this time or given me my P45.

How can I get my notice and P45 from them - what are my options?

Answer (score 5):

I would send a polite but firm letter requesting that they pay you what you are owed - within 7 days and say that you will take them to an industrial tribunal - which will cost them a lot.

You can approach the CAB (Citizens Advice Bureau) or if you area a member of a union they should also be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example of what that letter would look like?

Comment: Unfortunately that would be offering legal advice which is against the rules of the site.

Though As an experienced Lay TU case handler in theory I can give advice on UK employment law. Stackexchange  probably wisely doesn't want to open any potential problems around legal advice.

Comment: Maybe also report them to the HMRC for not giving you a P45.

Comment: You don't even have to report them; just call HMRC and tell them that you lost your job and haven't received your money and your P45, and they will tell you what to do (and give the company a nice friendly call as well, especially if the company hasn't paid your taxes).